# The getter 'image' was called on null

Tags: firebase, flutter

i am trying to fetching list of url from cloud fire store and using that fetching images from fire base storage.

images loaded as expected but console show some errors as below.

```
I/flutter (24353): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown during a 
scheduler callback:
I/flutter (24353): The getter 'image' was called on null.
I/flutter (24353): Receiver: null
I/flutter (24353): Tried calling: image
I/flutter (24353): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
```

what i tried.

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection('images').snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context,
          AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return new CircularProgressIndicator();
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return new Center(child: new CircularProgressIndicator());
          default:
            return new StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              crossAxisCount: 4,
              itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                String imgPath = snapshot.data.documents[i]['link'];
                return new Material(
                  elevation: 8.0,
                  borderRadius:
                  new BorderRadius.all(new Radius.circular(8.0)),
                  child: new InkWell(
                    child: new Hero(
                      tag: imgPath,
                      child: new FadeInImage(
                        image: new NetworkImage(imgPath),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        placeholder: new AssetImage("images/images.jpg"),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
              staggeredTileBuilder: (i) =>
              new StaggeredTile.count(2, i.isEven ? 2 : 3),
              mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
              crossAxisSpacing: 8.0,
            );
          }
        },
    )
```

Comment: It could be because operation is asynchronous and initially value received could be null. Add a condition for null.

Comment: i already have a condition for it. i just updated my question. any further suggestion. any hint is appreciated.

Comment: Can you confirm all documents are having valid image URLs Firestore.instance.collection('images').snapshots(). I think one of the document is having URL value as null.

Comment: i checked and all the images are loading as expected.

Comment: Your error is of line image: new NetworkImage(imgPath), in any one document imgPath is null. Check your documents.

Comment: Print imgPath in your function and check if any value is null.

Comment: i verify all the link and with printing in console. all the links are good.

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya did you find any solution? having the exact same issue with StaggeredGridView

Answer (score 0):

If the images load fine but have null errors as you've mentioned, it's likely that the first run of `Widget build()` has null image URL on `NetworkImage()`. A workaround is to have a null check on `imgPath`. The `placeholder` parameter will only work well if the image URL isn't null, as demonstrated [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/images/fading-in-images).

```dart
FadeInImage(
    // if imgPath != null, display Networkimage, else display AssetImage
    image: (imgPath != null)? NetworkImage(imgPath) : AssetImage("images/images.jpg"),
    fit: BoxFit.cover,
),
```

Another option here is by using `loadingBuilder` and `errorBuilder` constructors on [`Image.network()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.network.html)

```dart
Image.network(
     imgPath,
     fit: BoxFit.cover,
     // display progress indicator
     loadingBuilder: (BuildContext context, Widget child,
         ImageChunkEvent loadingProgress) {
       if (loadingProgress == null) return child;
       return CircularProgressIndicator(
         value: loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes != null
             ? loadingProgress.cumulativeBytesLoaded /
                 loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes
             : null,
       );
     },
     // display error image
     errorBuilder: (BuildContext context, Object exception, StackTrace stackTrace) {
         debugPrint('Error loading image: $exception \n Stack trace: $stackTrace');
         return Image.asset('images/error_loading.png');
     },
),
```